# how group apiResource route and other routes together?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, grouping

I am using `apiResource` and other routes. I grouped them like below:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'posts'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => '/{post}'], function () {
         Route::put('lablabla', [PostController::class, 'lablabla']);
    });
    Route::apiResource('/', PostController::class, [
        'names' => [
            'store' => 'create_post',
            'update' => 'edit_post',
        ]
    ]);
});
```

all apiResource routes except `index` and `store` do not work! How should I group routes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax for routing is wrong,

**Notes**

1. You will provide a **uri** for the apiResource (plural)

- eg.  Route::apiResource('posts', PostController::class);

2. Your name of resource route is wrong

- Get this out https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes
- it should be

  ```
   Route::apiResource('posts', PostController::class)->names([
        'store' => 'create_post',
        'update' => 'edit_post',
   ]);
  ```

3. No need of repeating **Route::group**, you can just write your routes like this

   ```
    Route::prefix('posts')->group(function () {
        Route::put('lablabla', [PostController::class, 'lablabla']); 
    });

    Route::apiResource('posts', PostController::class)->names([
        'store' => 'create_post',
        'update' => 'edit_post',
    ]);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect, there is a names method. See the documentation here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-routes.